# Split a String and store value in Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string "**My name is Aditya Kumar**" and I want to split the string by space and store into a array like:

```
var arr = {My,name,is,Aditya,Kumar};
```

How can i do this?

Comment: your expected output does not look like an array.should be var arr = ["My","name","is","Aditya","Kumar"];

Answer (score 3):

That will be space not backspace, And I think you are getting confused the syntax of array from other languages.

In javascript the array syntax is `[]` not `{}`.

Use this

```
"My name is Aditya Kumar".split(' ')
```

Output

```
["My", "name", "is", "Aditya", "Kumar"]
```

In javascript arrays are like above not like which you have mentioned.

Comment: how this will be as OP's expected output?

Comment: @SKRocks He is expecting an array and this is the array not the one he is mentoning, he might be confused with C syntax.

Comment: I thought he is confused with java string array :-)

Comment: @TamilVendhan could be I'm not sure, I've written `might`.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.split(' ');
```

It's a basic javascript function

Answer (score 0):

`split` already returns an array of strings:

```
var arr =  "My name is Aditya Kumar".split(" ")
// returns [My, name, is, Aditya, Kumar]
```

Also note that what you have is an object, not an array, arrays are identified by square brackets (`[]`).

Comment: how this will be as OP's expected output?

Comment: I don't see the difference between my output and his, his variable is an object but he said he wants an array, he simply made a mistake in the variable definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
"My name is Aditya Kumar".split(' ');//["My", "name", "is", "Aditya", "Kumar"]
```

Comment: how this will be as OP's expected output?

Comment: `var arr = {My,name,is,Aditya,Kumar}; ` is not a valid javascript array.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
var str = 'My name is Aditya Kumar';
var res = str.split(' ');
```

The result of res will be an array with the values:

Comment: I didnt downvote. But i think the reason is your code is wrong. There is no `comma` in the string. So, your output will be `["My name is Aditya Kumar"]`

Comment: @Rex edit it again. Because it is locked. So the person wo downvotes cannot remove it

Answer (score -1):

this is the correct answer as OP expected

```
var str = "My name is Aditya Kumar";
var new_str = "{"+str.replace(/ /g, ',')+"}";
alert(new_str);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
{My,name,is,Aditya,Kumar}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/39334/)

Comment: that is not an array for me.also the OP is unclear about what is the expected output.

Comment: @BOSS ya may be. just put the  OP's expected string. or may be he can require that format and unable to explain it